# Running appcfg.py

Tags: google-app-engine

I have python + google app engine installed on a windows XP machine. Google App engine is installed in the default directory of python25.

How do I run appcfg.py from command line?

I tried running it after changing directory to python25 but I get an error that the program is not a valid win32.exe

I also tried running it directly from c:\program files\google\google_appengine but I also get an error.

Secondly, I need to run appcfg with the rollback option. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you needs to assign python scripts to python.exe or do the following [Path to Python]\python.exe [Path to appcfg]\appcfg.py rollback [path to app].

Comment: I tried that; starting with C:\Python25\python.exe....... but I get the error message that C:\Python25\python.exe is not a valid win32 application

Comment: I re-installed python. After the re-installation, I noticed that python.exe in Python25 directory no longer had a size of 0. Also, all I had to do now was to type appcfg.py rollback [path to app]. Thanks